# Why not show both down and up votes by default. ala Youtube?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting

I have the feeling it might help having less of a black or white questions or answers system.

I think having it set by default would be a better behaviour.

Lets add some shades of grey in here... any amount will do IMO. Fifty might be good though :)

I know I can always leave a comment, but I'm starting to dislike comments. They tend to take a less than courteous slope (moderators might recognize why I state that).

Comment: http://serverfault.com/privileges/

Comment: `I know I can always leave a comment, but I'm starting to dislike comments. They tend to take a less than courteous slope (moderators might recognize why I state that).` <- Comments are still bound by [the etiquette rule](http://serverfault.com/faq#etiquette). If you see people violating that please flag the comments. I'm not aware of any big breaches of civility recently, but if I've missed them please feel free to stop by chat and point them out so I can smack the responsible person(s) around.

Comment: "moderators might recognize why I state that" - Is that from guilt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me?

[image: Works for me.]

Comment: Can you send me the link to that specific question? I'd like to see it in my browser. If it works I'll go sober out.

Comment: @alex Question is [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/459692/would-data-recovery-be-possible-after-acer-hidden-partition-reinstall). Click on the question's score to see the voting details.

Comment: Thank, you. I will do a little edit to my original question.

Comment: This is unlocked at a certain rep threshold. 2k or 3k, I think.

Comment: @MDMarra http://meta.serverfault.com/a/4057/23067

Comment: Aaaaand, he's past that threshold. I need to start paying attention

Comment: @MDMarra...me too I need to pay more attention...I didn't even notice I could do that :S

Answer (score 7):

This comes in with the [Established User](https://serverfault.com/privileges/established-user) Privilege at 1000 rep.